# Swift How remove searchController bottom border?

Tags: ios, swift, border, searchbar

This page has tableView and SearchController. My problem is searchController borders. I can't remove borders

I tried: 
[Remove border between View and Search Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631567/remove-border-between-view-and-search-bar)

[Remove navigation bar bottom line when using search controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818314/remove-navigation-bar-bottom-line-when-using-search-controller)

[Remove 1px line at top of UISearchController in large titles UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52346812/remove-1px-line-at-top-of-uisearchcontroller-in-large-titles-uinavigationbar)

[How to hide UINavigationBar 1px bottom line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226965/how-to-hide-uinavigationbar-1px-bottom-line)

[How can I remove border bottom of UINavigationBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942141/how-can-i-remove-border-bottom-of-uinavigationbar)

[image]

```
           if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                   let scb = searchController.searchBar
                   scb.tintColor = UIColor.white
                   scb.barTintColor = UIColor.white
                   scb.layer.masksToBounds = true
                   scb.layer.borderWidth = 10
                   scb.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

                   if let textfield = scb.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
                       textfield.layer.borderWidth = 2
                       textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                       //textfield.textColor = // Set text color
                       if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {
                           // Background color
                           backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                           backgroundview.layer.borderWidth = 0

                           backgroundview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                           // Rounded corner
                           backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
                           backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
                       }
                   }
                   if let navigationbar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
                       navigationbar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
                   }
                               navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

               }
                navigationItem.searchController = searchController

       navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never

       self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold) ]
       searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
       searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Candies"
       navigationItem.searchController = searchController
       definesPresentationContext = true
```

How fix this issue? Any has idea?

Comment: This is navigation bar separator View instead of SearchBar. Check again

Comment: try this one : let navigationBar = navigationController!.navigationBar
navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "BarBackground"),
                                                        for: .default)
navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

Comment: Thanks for answer. when you remove it SearchController getting lost line. Your code outputs: https://imgur.com/nQ8ogmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to set the navigation bar's background and shadow images to an empty image.

i did one more change, just comment

> navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never

and Add these two line

> navigationbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
>   navigationbar.shadowImage = UIImage()

Here is the complete code :

```
 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let scb = searchController.searchBar
            scb.tintColor = UIColor.white
            scb.barTintColor = UIColor.white
            scb.layer.masksToBounds = true
            scb.layer.borderWidth = 10
            scb.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

            if let textfield = scb.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
                textfield.layer.borderWidth = 2
                textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                //textfield.textColor = // Set text color
                if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {
                    // Background color
                    backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                    backgroundview.layer.borderWidth = 0

                    backgroundview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                    // Rounded corner
                    backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
                    backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
                }
            }
            if let navigationbar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
                navigationbar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
                navigationbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
                navigationbar.shadowImage = UIImage()

            }
            navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        }

//        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold) ]
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Candies"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true



override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if let navigationbar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
        navigationbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationbar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```

Please check updated code.

Comment: Thanks for answer @rmaddy. I did this and outputs still same. Your code https://imgur.com/GqljhkG, output : https://imgur.com/nQ8ogmx

Comment: @yusufdemirkoparan Not my answer. I just made an edit.

Comment: @rmaddy ah sorry :). Thanks for answers Sumit Garg.

Comment: check updated Comment, i try this code in sample project and it is working.

Comment: @SumitGarg Hi Sumit you can share me your sample project?

Comment: here is the sample code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i2IC0SHUaaBIsABXBMbI-q6b3ifQIwXr

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension of UISearchController:

```
extension UISearchController {

var hairlineView: UIView? {
    let barBackgroundView = searchBar.superview?.subviews.first { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "_UIBarBackground" }
    
    guard let background = barBackgroundView else { return nil }
    return background.subviews.first { $0.bounds.height == 1 / self.traitCollection.displayScale }
    } 
}
```

Call this in view will layout subview:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    self.navigationItem.searchController?.hairlineView?.isHidden = true
}
```